# Local variables from within the pickle command string?

Tags: python, pickle

This is for a security competition, please don't yell at me :)

I'm trying to access local variables from with the string passed to `pickle.loads()`. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
local_var = 1
pickle.loads('''c__builtin__
eval
(c__builtin__
compile
(S"print local_var"
S"error_output_file"
S"exec"
tRtR.''')
```

However, I get the following error: `NameError: name 'local_var' is not defined`

Indeed, when I inspect the local variables, they are totally different from what I would expect:

```
pickle.loads("""c__builtin__
locals
(tR.""")
```

gives

```
{'args': (),
 'func': <function locals>,
 'self': <pickle.Unpickler instance at 0x108af3830>,
 'stack': []}
```

What is going on here, and how do I do what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pickle.loads()` function has no direct access to the locals of the code you called `.loads()` *from*. It has it's own scope. In this case, you are looking at the local namespace of one of the methods on the `pickle.Unpicler` instance that is handling your `.loads()` call.

You'd have to use [`sys._getframe()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to access the calling stack, then look at the `.f_locals` mapping of individual frames to reach locals of calling functions.

Guessing from the [`pickle` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3436769a7964/Lib/pickle.py) I'd say you need to skip 3 frames, the current dispatch method, the `Unpickler.load` method calling the current dispatch method, and the module level `loads()` function, so `sys._getframe(3).f_locals['local_var']` aught to get you the reference you want.